# MatDialog not displaying HTML tags with injected data

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-dialog

As shown in the added images, it does render the second component but the text is blank.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It is getting the injected data as shown by it outputting in the console. I have also tried this same code in another blank angular project that doesn't have much and it works over there. I have been trying to solve this for the last few days and nothing has worked. Have found EntryComponents but it doesn't exist on Angular 17. Also tried NgZone which also didn't work. If I add the injected code with Hello World text, that also disappears and doesn't show any text even though it is hard-coded text.

Pop Up Component.html

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h2>{{name}}</h2>
```

PopUpcomponent.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA
} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pop-up-component',
  templateUrl: './pop-up-component.component.html',
  styleUrl: './pop-up-component.component.scss',
})
export class PopUpComponent {
  name: any;
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    this.name = data.name;
    console.log('popupcomponent ' + this.name);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
```

Main Component HTML

```
<div class="row">
       <button class="btn" (click)="openDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
</div>
```

Main Component TS

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, NgZone, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../Services/data.service';
import { LoginServiceService } from '../Services/login-service.service';
import {
  MatDialog,
  MatDialogRef,
} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { PopUpComponent } from '../pop-up-component/pop-up-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-component',
  templateUrl: './main-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private login: LoginServiceService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private dialogRef: MatDialog,
  ) {}
openDialog() {
   this.dialogRef.open(PopUpComponent, {
    data: {
      name:'artist'
    }
   })
  }
}
```

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what do you see in your console.log

Comment: @Andrei I see the data. the name artist is passed to the pop up component

Comment: where is your MatDialogModule imported? edit: also check if you're providing something (cant recall, but this happened to me because I was providing in both the popup declaration and the caller declaration. The popup provider overrides the caller provider, so the dialog_data does not exist. Removing this from the popup declarating module solved it for me)

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli I have imported the MatDialogModule in the app module file. And can I ask what you mean by providing in both the popup and caller declaration? Do you mean injecting the data twice?